# Aptana Studio 3 (build 3.6.0.201407100658) how to change font colors (pydev)

Tags: python, aptana

I am very new to programming and just started using Aptana Studio 3 for python development. I just updated the application and now the syntax coloring is so dark for normal variables that I can't see what I am typing. How do I change this? Before updating to the latest build I didn't have this problem. Unfortunately I don't know what build I was running before updating... :(